# Dynamic Location Offsetting while Desktop Video Capture in FFPMEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video, screen-capture

is there a way to dynamically change offsets during screen capture ?

but this offset values are static (eg. 66 and 77) and we cannot change these values during video recording. simply I am trying to record screen with according to mouse coordinates which are ofsure changing while video recording starts.

eg.

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 77 -offset_y 66 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop output.mp4
```

Comment: `gdigrab` doesn't support dynamically change offsets. We may capture full screen, and use [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter, for selecting the ROI (region of interest). Updating the ROI according to mouse coordinates, is not possible using FFmpeg by it's own. It's possible to update FFmpeg parameters using `zmqsend` utility. Do you have a way to get the mouse coordinates, compute the ROI coordinates, and pass them to `zmqsend` as command line arguments?